# Expanded split view controller on iPhone 6 plus in portrait

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus

Is it possible to make a split view controller behave the same way on an iPhone 6 Plus as it does on iPad?

So I don't want it to collapse in portrait mode on iPhone 6 Plus but act the same way as it does on iPad when in portrait mode.

Comment: Looks like it collapses in portrait on the iPhone but splits in landscape. http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/  If that doesn't suit you there might be open source projects that accomplish what you want: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=split

Answer (score 1):

It is: you have to create a VC with a `containerView` and put the `splitView` in the container with a embed segue and then override trait collection on the prepare for segue of that view:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let trait = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular)
    setOverrideTraitCollection(trait, forChildViewController: segue.destinationViewController)
}
```